# Download non-latin script language file from google translate

Tags: android, binary, download, translate

I'm trying to download a mp3 file generated with google translate. It works fine with languages with Latin script, but if I for example try Thai it dosen't work at all.

Any one have a suggestion? This is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mButton;

    private File mOutputFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String uri = Uri.parse("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts")
                        .buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter("tl", "th")
                        .appendQueryParameter("q", "ก")
                        .build().toString();

                mOutputFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "sound.mp3");

                try {
                    new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(uri))
                            .getEntity().writeTo(
                            new FileOutputStream(mOutputFile));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speak);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play(mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        });
    }

    private void play(String path) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out awhile ago and remember I should post my findings. I needed to add another parmeter to the url:

.appendQueryParameter("ie", "utf-8")

Now it works perfect.